# Array of objects with values pass to useQuery in the custom hook and it become empty?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I got a question. Hope you can tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.

I'm trying to pass an array of objects to useQuery in the custom hook.

I did a console log and there are values in the array. But after it went into the function that is calling axios, the array become empty.

Here is the code:

// in the custom hook

```
const AddNewEvents = async (newEvents) => {
    console.log('AddNewEvents fn: ', newEvents); //showing empty array
    //return await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}Event`, newEvents);
};

export const useAddNewEventsData = (newEvents, onSuccess, onError) => {
    console.log('before arrow function: ', newEvents); //got values
    return useQuery('add-new-events-query', () => AddNewEvents(newEvents), {
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
        onError: onError,
        enabled: false,
    });
};
```

// in App.js

```
const [newEvents, setNewEvents] = useState([]);

const addNewEventsResp = useAddNewEventsData(
    newEvents,
    onSuccessUseAddNewEventsData,
    onErrorUseAddNewEventsData
);
```

and I call addNewEventsResp.refetch() after populating the newEvents array of object.

Comment: I try the following but still no value.

`code`
const AddNewEvents = async (id) => {
    console.log('AddNewEvents fn: ', id) //0
}

export const useAddNewEventsData = (newEvents, onSuccess, onError) => {
    const eventId = 123
    console.log('before arrow fn: ', eventId) //123
    return useQuery('add-new-events-query', () => AddNewEvents(eventId), {
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
        onError: onError,
        enabled: false,
    })
}`code`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you have not passed the newEvents on the function parameter. Can you try this:

```
export const useAddNewEventsData = (newEvents, onSuccess, onError) => {
console.log('before arrow function: ', newEvents); //got values
return useQuery('add-new-events-query', (newEvents) => AddNewEvents(newEvents), { // here (newEvents) =>
    onSuccess: onSuccess,
    onError: onError,
    enabled: false,
});
```

};

Comment: This is what I see in the console after trying your suggestion. AddNewEvents fn: > {queryKey: Array(1), pageParam: undefined}

Comment: The array is still empty.